# Use grub config of second Ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have two Ubuntu partitions, Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. I use for the 99% of time the partition with U18.04, but I see that the grub config are taken from the partition with 16.04.Now, I have a problem with a kernel version with U18.04 and I am not able to boot with the older version because the grub manager in U16.04 does not recognize U18.04 kernels (while if a I do `sudo update-grub` from 18.04 everything is detected).

My partitions are depicted in the figure:
[image]
Where `sda1` contains U16.04 and `sda5` U18.05. `sda3` is a partition or data accessible from boot the OSs.

So I would that during the boot the grub configurations produced by U18.04 are used, but I do not know how to do.

Comment: It looks like 18.04 is installed in EFI mode, but 16.04 is installed in legacy BIOS boot mode. To use only 18.04’s GRUB installation, try disabling Legacy Boot.

Comment: Alternatively, ensure the ‘Ubuntu’ boot option appears before any legacy BIOS boot options, such as the hard drive. You should be able to change these settings for legacy BIOS boot, or the boot order, from your system firmware setup utility.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: @galexite Legacy boot is disabled and "Ubuntu" is the first option in the boot order

Comment: @guiverc I want to use the grub configs of my Ubuntu 18.04 and then remove the partition with U16.04

Comment: It might be worth removing Ubuntu 16.04 anyway, and then running Boot-Repair from a live DVD or USB. That way, it will not inherit the old configuration, because it no longer exists. The GRUB core.img is a legacy BIOS requirement.

Comment: should I also remove the partition with grub2core.img (i.e. sda4)?